# SQLite3 - Finding average values when a new variable is introduced

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am working with SQLite3 and I have 4 tables:

```
HAVING foreignstudent = 'TRUE'
ORDER BY max(score) desc;
```

It seems like adding that in will allow the values to be printed only where foreignstudent is true. However, it does not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at your first query first:

```
SELECT sid, name, crsid, avg(grade)
FROM classmate natural join took natural join classSection
natural join class
GROUP BY crsid
ORDER BY max(score) desc;
```

Apart from mentioning tables that are not defined in the question, there are three issues/bad habits with this query.  First, you are not using table aliases that specify where the columns are coming from.  The second is that columns are in the `select` clause but not in the `group by`.  The third is the use of `natural join`.  `Natural join` *seems* really useful, but what it does depends on the underlying structure of the table -- adding, dropping, or renaming a column affects the join, not by causing an error but by producing different results.  Yuck!  So, try writing this query as:

```
SELECT cm.sid, cm.name, c.crsid, avg(t.grade)
FROM classmate cm join
     took t
     using (sid) join
     classSection cs
     using (secid) join
     course c
     using (crsid)
GROUP BY cm.sid, cm.name, c.crsid;
```

Next, if you want to filter on just foreign students, add a `where` clause, not a `having` clause:

```
SELECT cm.sid, cm.name, c.crsid, avg(grade)
FROM classmate cm join
     took t
     using (sid) join
     classSection cs
     using (secid) join
     course c
     using (crsid)
WHERE cm.foreignstudent = 1
GROUP BY cm.sid, cm.name, c.crsid;
```

In SQLite, "true" is the value `1`.